# How to remove space between line numbers and editor in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

This is a screenshot from my new installation of Phpstorm on Debian. The only configuration I've done so far is install the Material Theme.

[image]

How do I reduce the (enormous) spacing between the line numbers and the editor itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah - figured it out! I had accidently entered *Distraction free mode*.

I disabled it (view -> Exit Distraction Free Mode) and everything is normal.

Comment: You can always double tap `shift` and search for `distraction` :)